# Relative Concentrations of Reactants and Products at Equilibrium

Tags: equilibrium

I cannot understand what makes a reaction at equilibrium lie far to the right (large K) or far to the left (small K). What exactly makes the product or the reactant concertation larger than the other when the reaction producing the products (forward reaction) and the reaction producing the reactants (reverse reaction) have the same rate, and rate is change in concentration over time.

When I was reading to find an answer, I came across the definition of the equilibrium constant as a ratio of the rate constants of the forward reaction to the rate constant of the reverse reaction. Does that have some effect on determining the concentration which reaction species will be greater at equilibrium, given that at the end of the day, the rates of the reactions are the same. If the rate constant does have an effect, then what is the factor determining how large the rate constant at a given temperature is.

I just can't wrap my head around it, if the rates of the reactions are the same, (and obviously the initial concentrations of the reaction species have no effect on K), then there must be another factor affecting the concentrations of the reactants at equilibrium, but what is it?

Comment: The point is, the rates of the forward and backward reactions are equal at and only at the reaction equilibrium. If for $\ce{A <=> B}$ and $[\ce{A}] = [\ce{B}]$ isf the forward rate  (much) bigger than the backward rate, then K>1 ( K >>1 ) and vice versa. $$\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{B}]}{\mathrm{d}t} = k_f[\mathrm{A}] - k_b[\ce{B}]$$ and similarly for $\ce{A}$, assuming the reaction is elementary.